# Cannot plot 2 separate graphs using FlotJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, flot

Im trying to plot 2 separate graphs (actually it will be 9 but for now there are only 2) using flotJS, somehow the data mixes and plots the same mixed data on both graphs

Here is my JS code:

```
var graphData1, graphData2, graphData3 = [];
var graphBuffer = 1000;
var xmin = 0;
var xmax = 5;

var options = {
    xaxes: [
        {position: 'bottom', autoScale: 'none', min: 0, max: 5}
    ],
    yaxes: [
        {position: 'left', autoScale: 'none', min: -1.5, max: 1.5}
    ],
    zoom: {interactive: true},
    pan: {interactive: true}
};


function deleteGraph() {
    graphData1 = graphData2 = graphData3 = [];

    $.plot("#graph1", [{graphData1}], options);
    $.plot("#graph2", [{graphData2}], options);
    //$.plot("#graph3", [{graphData3}], options);
}

function updateGraph(data) {

    var datatmp = data.data;

    // Formatea y Almacena datos a graficar
    datatmp.forEach(function (sample) {
        graphData1.push([parseFloat(sample.timestamp.toFixed(4)), parseFloat(sample.sensor1.toFixed(4))]);
        //graphData2.push([parseFloat(sample.timestamp.toFixed(4)), parseFloat(sample.sensor2.toFixed(4))]);
    });

    $.plot("#graph1", [graphData1], options);
    $.plot("#graph2", [graphData2], options);

}
```

and with this code the output is:

[image: graph result 1]

As you can see its plotting the same information on both graphs even when `//graphData2.push([parseFloat(sample.timestamp.toFixed(4)), parseFloat(sample.sensor2.toFixed(4))]);` is commented

However if i remove the comment the result is this:

[image: graph result 2]

As you can see its mixing the data and plotting the same mixed data on both graphs

How can i plot different data on different graphs?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `graphData1 = graphData2` so they are the same array. Then you push all your data points into that one array which is shown in both charts.

Replace

```
var graphData1, graphData2, graphData3 = [];

// and

function deleteGraph() {
    graphData1 = graphData2 = graphData3 = [];
```

with

```
var graphData1 = [], graphData2 = [], graphData3 = [];

// and

function deleteGraph() {
    graphData1 = [];
    graphData2 = [];
    graphData3 = [];
```